# Anyone have ideas for this zip script?

Tags: php, archive

This is my script that I use to put the folder, which name is in `$id` variable into an archive.

```
$sourcefolder="../uploads/fail/$id/";
$zipfilename="fordownload/$id.zip";
$timeout=5000;
$dirlist = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sourcefolder);
$filelist = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirlist);
ini_set('max_execution_time', $timeout);
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open("$zipfilename", ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Error");
}
foreach ($filelist as $key=>$value)
{
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("Error");
}
$zip->close();
redict("$zipfilename",0);
```

The problem is that I want to put only the folder `$id` in the archive, without prefix `../uploads/fail/`, but I don't know how. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the core of your code:

```
$dirlist = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sourcefolder);
$filelist = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirlist);
$zip = new ZipArchive();
foreach ($filelist as $key => $value) {
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("Error");
}
```

You're invoking a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator), which is a [FilesystemIterator](http://php.net/class.filesystemiterator), which itself is a [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/class.directoryiterator).  Inside your `foreach`, `$value` is a [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/class.splfileinfo).

Our first shot will be this:

```
foreach ($filelist as $path => $fileinfo) {
    $zip->addFile($fileinfo->getRealPath(), $fileinfo->getBasename()) or die ("Error");
}
```

[getRealPath](http://php.net/splfileinfo.getrealpath) returns the same thing `realpath` does, while [getBasename](http://php.net/splfileinfo.getbasename) returns just the filename itself, like `basename` would.

However, this won't work as expected.  See, it's a *recursive* directory iterator, and this flattens the paths of any files in subdirectories.  I'll come back and edit in a solution to this some time later if you can't crack it on your own.

Comment: It works better now, but I have to find a solution for this problem:
http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/7231/casus.png